# What kind of code do i have to put in OnCreate() and when do i have to put it in OnCreateView()?

Tags: android, oncreate, findviewbyid

I am trying to understand when i should use the oncreate method or the oncreateview method.

I am a little bit confused. First i had some code including statements like findViewById() in the OnCreate() method. But it always responded with a null pointer Exception, then someone told me i should put it in the OnCreateView() method. It worked, but i do not understand when and what for code i should put in the OnCreate() or when and what i should put in the OnCreateView(). Could someone please explain this to me.

Comment: It showed a `NullPointerException` probably because you tried to call the method `findViewById(..)` before the layout is brought into view using `setContentView(...)` otherwise I don't see any reason for `NullPointerException` to show in `onCreate()` just by calling `findViewById`.

Answer (score 0):

In my code, the methodology is the following:

ACTIVITY code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_container);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    if (saveInstanceState == null)
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.activity_container_container, new MyFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener()
    {
        public void onBackStackChanged()
        {
            int backCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
            if (backCount == 0)
            {
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void myInterface()
{
    System.out.println("Do stuff;");
}
```

FRAGMENT code:

```
private int titleId;
private Button placeholderButton;

private MyInterface activity_myInterface;

public MyFragment()
{
    super();
    this.titleId = R.string.my_actionbar_title;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try
    {
        activity_myInterface = (MyInterface)activity;
    }
    catch(ClassCastException e)
    {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "MyInterface interface needs to be implemented by Activity.", e);
        throw e;
    }
}

//this is an interface defined by me
@Override
public int getActionBarTitleId()
{
    return titleId;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfragment, container, false);
    placeholderButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.myfragment_placeholderbtn);
    placeholderButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v == placeholderButton)
    {
        System.out.println("Do more stuff");
    }
}
```

Where R.layout.activity_container is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_container_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This way the Activity is responsible for containing the Fragment (and this fragment is created in onCreate()) and the Fragment is responsible for the display of UI and the event handling. You can have more than one fragment on an Activity, though, that's what they primarily were designed for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Activity, then you can just stay away from the onCreateView.

Just stick to the default [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle):

The layout (content) is inflated (created) at the onCreate method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
}
```

Then once it has been inflated you are ready to use it and manipulate views that belong to it.

`findViewById()` returned null for you because the layout was not ready to be used and that's because it was not yet inflated. You can use `findViewById()` after `setContentView()` in `onCreate`.

`findViewById()` is a method that can be pretty hard on the performance (if called many times), so you should get all the views you need in onCreate and save them to an instance variable like:

TextView textView1, textView2;

Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
    textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textview2);
    ...
}

And use them from onStart:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (textView1 != null) textView1.setText("myText");
    if (textView2 != null) textView2.setText("some other text");
}
```